# Tem jeito melhor de agrupar "ORs" em Python sem ter que digitar a variável toda hora?

Tags: python, if

**Exemplo:**

```
letra = input('Digite uma letra: ')


if(letra == 'a' or letra == 'e' or letra == 'i' or letra == 'o' or letra == 'u'):

        print('Vogal')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [operador `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
letra = input('Digite uma letra: ')
if letra in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
    print('Vogal')
```

Claro que se só quer fazer a verificação e depois não vai usar a letra para mais nada, nem precisa de uma variável:

```
if input('Digite uma letra: ') in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
    print('Vogal')
```

---

E antes que alguém sugira, existe uma alternativa que funciona para esses casos, mas com alguns poréns:

```
if letra in 'aeiou':
```

O problema é que neste caso também entra no `if` se o usuário digitar `aei`, por exemplo, já que o operador `in`, quando aplicado a uma string, verifica se `letra` é uma substring de `aeiou`. Se quer que as opções sejam somente as vogais (ou seja, a variável `letra` só pode ter um caractere), use a opção anterior.

---

Outra alternativa - desnecessariamente complicada para este caso - é usar regex (disponíveis no [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

```
import re

if re.match('^[aeiou]$', input('Digite uma letra: ')):
    print('Vogal')
```

No caso, a regex verifica se a string contém apenas uma das letras ("a", "e", "i", "o" ou "u"). Ela usa os [marcadores](http://regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string, garantindo assim que ela só tem o que está na expressão. E também usa a [classe de caracteres](https://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[aeiou]`, que pega qualquer uma das vogais.

Mas para um caso simples como esse, usar regex é um exagero, deixei só como curiosidade mesmo.